# problems occurred when installing slap package by using opam in ocaml

Tags: package, ocaml, opam

I try to do some linear algebra calculating in OCaml. And I had installed Lacaml package. Knowing the slap package is more user friendly, I decided to use this package instead of Lacaml. I did install slap package successfully by typing "`opam install slap`". But when compiling a file by typing "`ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package slap,slap.ppx -short-paths jacobi.ml`", the error

```
"ocamlfind: Package `slap_ppx' not found"
```

occurred. I has been trying a lot to deal with it, but can't. 
I has tried to make the package by hand. But a problem called

```
"File "ppx/ppx_slap.ml", line 21, characters 0-15:
Error: Unbound module Ast_helper"
```

occurred. I had no idea the "Ast_helper" module is in which package.

Above is all descriptions about my problems. If someone had installed the slap, please help me.

Comment: are you sure that you didn't type `slap_ppx`? There should be `slap.ppx`. Besides, your command works for me. Maybe you should try to `opam update` and `opam upgrade`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing slap package. Your command works well for me, but opam sometimes fails to install packages. I have encountered broken dependency for slap on opam, but `opam update` and `opam upgrade` solves such problems. Maybe it's helpful for you. `ppx_tools` is not required for slap package because compiler-libs of OCaml 4.02 supports `Ast_helper`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Ast_helper` module is used in PPX development, so it makes sense that a PPX would require it, but I'm surprised that installation succeeded if this is the case. I believe that this module is included in the `ppx_tools` package, which may be installed with the command

```
opam update && opam install ppx_tools
```